Error While Implementing Migrate Command in Prisma: How to Resolve?
I am Working on Twitter-Clone, where I am facing issue on Twitter-server side while implementing Prisma.
more details- when I am trying to create a dataBase table of MODEL USER in schema.prisma and trying to connect it with superBase by running "npx prisma migrate dev --name added_user_model" command then this goes under processing but does not execute as it has to be.
As you can see in the terminal, the command is running and it keep on process like this only.

What I have tried?

I have rechecked the DATABASE_URL from SUPERBASE it also right,
I have installed the prisma/client and all prisma's dependencies.
I have checked and asked to chatGPT also but I am not getting my solution.
Expecting: After running that command a folder of migration should be created in prisma folder and migration must connect schema to superbase and create a USER MODEL table there. As you can see in this screenshot, this is how the command should work.



Please include relevant code and errors in the question, formatted appropriately

Actually it shows no error in my system, just it is kept on rendering this command but not executing it... @DaveNewton
As i have also attached screenshot of the problem and and expecting result both

Please include relevant code and errors in the question, formatted appropriately.

What is your error? Let it run it takes awhile sometimes

This here is the corrected host for your Postgres URL, you need to change the "6589" in your host to "5432". Another method is for you to change your pooler mode from "Transaction" to "Session" before copying your URL from superBase. You can use this link for reference.

Had the same issue and changing the port from "6542" to "5432" worked. Thanks
